# change video resolution to specific resolution using ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, ffmpeg

I am trying the change the resolution of some videos. The original video resolution is 1920x1080. first, I have to change the resolution to 640X480. for this I used the following code:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe', '-y', '-i', pname1, '-vf', 'scale=-1:480,setsar=1:1', '-c:v','libx264', '-c:a', 'copy', pname2])
```

when I used this code it produces a file that I cannot open and when I try to open it in cmd it said: "Invalid data found when processing input".
I changed the code to this to have 640X480:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe', '-y', '-i', pname1, '-vf', 'scale=640:-2,setsar=1:1', '-c:v','libx264', '-c:a', 'copy', pname2])
```

but the output is 640X360, what is the problem and how can I change the resolution from 1920x1080 to 640x480?
after that I have to change the resolution of videos to their original resolution (1920x1080) again.

Comment: How long is this video? Correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't saving the frames and resizing them and collecting them to another video is a good option?

Comment: Converting to `640x480` would stretch the video and destroy aspect ratio. Consider: `1080/1920=.5625` ~ `360/640=.5625` ~ `480/640=.75`. You should be happy that ffmpeg won't let you mess up the video.

Comment: Does this mean I can never change the resolution from 1080p to 480p? but we have videos with both resolutions. what is your suggestion? I have to have 854x480?

Comment: Find a video that is a perfect integer multiple of the video size you want. To do the size you want you need 960x720 or 1280x960. You have to consider, what do you expect ffmpeg to do with the "extra"? Does it just draw a marquee around everything, or chop off whatever doesn't fit.

Comment: I have to change the resolution of videos from 1080 to 480 and then again to 1080 and compute the PSNR value for the original video and this video. so I need to do this. I see this in papers that change the video resolution and make comparisons.

Comment: You can change the size to whatever you want but math is math and if it doesn't fit it isn't going to fit. You are either going to lose image data or end up with your video smashed into a marquee. If you divide width by height or vise-versa for the original size and the desired size, and the numbers do not match, then the video is not going to perfectly fit.

Comment: re: 854x480. `480/854=.562` ~ `480/640=.75` so, no. That size will not fit either. In the long run you are going to end up with bars above and below the video, which means it's not really 480p. It's a scaled 1080p crammed in a 480p window. This means that a 1/4 of your video data would just be black bars.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy is right on, but your comment on psnr is not clear. what are you comparing? 1080p before scaling vs. 480p after scaling? Or are you comparing 1080p vid to another 480p reference video? Because DAR is different between 1080p (16:9) and 480p (4:3) you are bound to have horrible psnr unless you're interested in a 4:3 region of 1080p video.

Comment: the original video resolution is 1080, then I change it to 480 and then again change it to 1080. now I compare the original video in 1080 with this video in 1080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **(1)**
>  *"The original video resolution is **1080**, 
>  > then I change it to **480**... 
>  > and then again change it back into **1080**. 
>
> ...Now I compare the original video in 1080 with this new video in 1080"*.
> **(2)** *"I see this in papers where you have to change the video resolution and then make comparisons."*

You can achieve all that with one command, where you `vf` scale **the input** (in memory, no saving needed) and then also later `scale` **the output** (with `-s` command). The order of command placement matters as to whether they affect the input or output parts.

Also since you're following some papers, most likely you are expected to use a specific scaling algorithm. When implementing these papers, they might require you to use bilinear or nearest neighbour or such...

You can set that scaling type/algorithm with: `sws_flags` (*eg:* `-sws_flags bicubic`).
Your options are: **neighbor**, **area**, **bilinear**, **bicubic**, **spline** (*for natural cubic*), **lanczos**...

I don't use Python but you can try some code like this:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe', '-y', '-i', pname1, '-vf', 'scale=640:480', 'sws_flags', 'bicubic', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-s', '1920:1080', '-c:a', 'copy', pname2])
```

Comment: your code  change my resolution from original resolution (1920x1080) to (640x480) and then from (640x480) to (1920x1080) with an estimation, right?

Comment: I'm not understanding _"with an estimation"_ but yes it will downsize the input of any size into 640x480 then upscale that new 640x480 data into an 1920x1080 data (expect some pixelation in image). Test it and ask anything...

Comment: I used your code in command with FFmpeg and by changing part of your code to "-scale=640:480" it works. but by using the above code in python it produces nothing. what is the problem?